# PrimeNG Tooltip on li HTML tag issue

Tags: javascript, html, angular, primeng

I have added `TooltipModule` to the imports in `app.module.ts`, but when I add `pTooltip="Hello World"` to the `<li>` tag, it won't show the tooltip. Any suggestions on what should I consider checking, or what could prevent it showing?

Comment: Have you added the styles for `primeng`?

Comment: @Derek.W yes, everything is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your implementation, importing `primeng` CSS files on frontend is missing.

You need to add these `CSS` files into html code.
It's good to import it on `index.html` file or `angular.json` file.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primeng@8.0.2/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css'/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/primeng@8.0.2/resources/primeng.min.css'/>
```

Comment: It's better to import it in `angular.json` file.